# Siri is unable to hear me

Tags: macos, siri

I’m unable to use Siri on my MacBook Pro with macOS Siera 10.12.4. It says that there is some “Siri Audio Problem.” 
The issue goes away when I restart my Mac, only to return after a very short time.

I have Dictation off.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tested your microphone?  Does it work on Skype (or similar)?  Can you record sound?  Have you tried an external mic?  This will help you determine if this is a hardware or a software issue.

Comment: I did not use external mic. On first screen, "input level" indicates that mic works fine. I suggest software issue because system reboot solves problem for a short time

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Cannot use Siri at all on my MacBook Pro - fine on my desktop iMac. I have Skype and Slack installed on the MacBook, and they work fine. I can also answer phone calls from my iPhone with the MacBook, so no problems with the microphone there, at all. Except for Siri, who seems to be deaf.

Comment: Here's the eternal question - have you tried rebooting your computer?

Comment: @Jackson1442, yes, I tried, and after reboot it worked fine for some time. Now I don't use Siri. No Siri - no problems :)

Answer (score 34):

I encountered that bug again and solved it with the following Terminal command:

```
sudo kill -9 `ps ax|grep 'coreaudio[a-z]' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Within 5 secs Siri works, no need to log out / reboot.

**Can somebody please check** whether this solution works for you as well or not. And maybe someone can come up with a clue of what to do with audio drivers to stop this from happening in the future?

Comment: Yep, I had exactly the same issue, Siri just wasn't responding. Ran this and it worked.

Comment: It worked for me too, High Sierra 10.13.3.

Comment: Just as a tangential note, after using the sudo command (above), if you are running something like Dragon for Mac (v6), this will appear to turn off the mic to that program. Simply quit out of that program and restart the program.

Comment: Also it is helping when siri hangs

Comment: Worked on macOS Mojave 10.14.1.

Comment: This also appears to halt audio playback in iTunes. However, it corrects itself in about 5 seconds. (macOS Mojave 10.14.1 MacBook Air 2017)